# Trouble using xpath with vbscript to edit xml file

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

I am trying to edit one attribute inside of a relatively large xml file using vbs. I am getting errors wheneverI try to use the selectSingleNode operation I am getting errors. This a shortened xml file that should give all of the information needed. I need to edit the  of the root-logger node to be WARN instead of INFO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jacorb"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    </extensions>
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
    </profile>
</server>
```

the script I am trying to use to edit the file looks like this

```
set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.async = false
xml.validateOnParse = false
xml.resolveExternals = false
xml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xml.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:m='urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1'"
slog4j = "WARN"

err.clear
on error resume next
xml.load (WScript.arguments(0))
if (err.number = 0) then
xml.selectSingleNode("//profile/subsystem/root-logger/level/@").text = slog4j
strResult = xml.save(WScript.arguments(0))
end if
```

It seems to be reading in the xml file correctly and having a problem with the xpath location to get to the attribute, but I used a similar format that worked on a previous file. Any suggestions would be wonderful. Sorry for the long block of code for the xml file. I didnt know how much i could remove while still giving enough information to get some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML uses two namespaces and you have to declare them both with different prefixes if you want to select elements in both namespaces. So with

```
set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.async = false
xml.validateOnParse = false
xml.resolveExternals = false
xml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xml.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:jb='urn:jboss:domain:1.2' xmlns:jl='urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1'"
slog4j = "WARN"

err.clear
on error resume next
xml.load (WScript.arguments(0))
if (err.number = 0) then
xml.selectSingleNode("//jb:profile/jl:subsystem/jl:root-logger/jl:level/@name").text = slog4j
strResult = xml.save(WScript.arguments(0))
end if
```

I get the attribute changed.

Comment: I tried that, but i still get an error on the selectSingleNode call. err.number becomes 424 and doesn't complete the operation

Comment: I have looked more closely at your XML sample and it has two namespaces so you need to use two prefixes if you want to use both the `profile` element in one namespace and the `subsystem` and its descendant in a second namespace. I have edited my answer with a tested code sample.

Comment: Thank you so much. I cant believe I overlooked that. perfect

Answer (score 0):

I'm a complete newb when it comes to XPath, but you should be able to select the element itself and then just update the attribute value using the `attributes` property:

```
xml.selectSingleNode("//profile/subsystem/root-logger/level").attributes.item(0).text = slog4j
```

Edit:

OK, so apparently this only works using XSL Pattern as the selection language but not XPath, so you'd have to comment out:

```
xml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

Comment: I get the same error attempting to do that as when I use the @ symbol because from my understanding since it is the only attribute, the @ symbol will get me to the same location as specifically calling the attribute.

Comment: In XPath you can use `@*` to select all attributes or `@foo` to select the `foo` attribute but having only `@` is a syntax error.

Comment: I was able to edit another xml file using only the @ without adding * or foo for a similar operation, but the code I have that works on a different XML file throws a ton of errors on this operation